# PhotoSwipe, Rails, Coffee doesn't work at all

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, photoswipe

Can't understand why PhotoSwipe doesn't show anything when I'm trying to add it into Rails project

1. Used this gem: https://github.com/skakri/photoswipe-rails
2. Step by step reproduced manual: https://photoswipe.com/documentation/getting-started.html#init-add-pswp-to-dom
3. Wrote 'click' handler
   But it shows nothing

Code I wrote:

```
<body>
  <!-- some Rails and other stuff -->
  <%= render 'shared/photoswipe' %> 
</body>
```

shared/_photoswipe.html.erb contains full copy of div class="pswp" from 2)
Invisible div successfully added at the end of page

Added some coffee code for PhotoSwipe init on click handler

```
$ ->
  $PhotoContainer = $('#MainPhoto')
  $PhotoContainer.click ->
    $pswpElement = document.querySelectorAll('.pswp')[0]
    $items = []
    $('.photo-item').each ->
      $Img = $(@)
      $items.push( { src: getUrlFromImg($Img).bigImgUrl, w: 1000, h: 1000 } )

    $options = {
      history: false,
      focus: false,
      index: 0
    }
    $gallery = new PhotoSwipe( $pswpElement, PhotoSwipeUI_Default, $items, $options)
    $gallery.init()
```

When I click on #MainPhoto container event fired, $items array correctly fills by image urls and sizes and calls PhotoSwipe init() function, but nothing shows on screen

Comment: What's intressting, div class="pswp" changes its properties on click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gem is improperly written
should add

```
@import "photoswipe/index";
@import "photoswipe/photoswipe";
@import "photoswipe/default-skin/default-skin";
```

into application.scss